# Please anyone refer me how can i check the boolean value in hashmap is greater than user defined integer

Tags: java, hashmap

```java
public class Booking implements seatcap {
    
    HashMap<String, Boolean> map = new HashMap<>(); 

    public Booking()
    {
        int c=0;
        
        for(c=0;c<seatsize;c++)
        {
            
            map.put("c",true);
        if(map.containsValue(true)==true)
        {
            if(c%10==0)
                System.out.println("\n");
            System.out.print("Seat"+ c+" Available\t");
        }
        
    }
    }
    
    public void compute(){
        
        System.out.println("Enter how many seats you want to book");
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int bookseat=sc.nextInt();
        sc.close();
        Iterator iter = map.entrySet().iterator();
        
        
    }
    
}
```

I have created a hashmap and mapped keys 1 to 100 to true. Now when user enters an integer number i should check whether the map contains the value true => user given integer number. Please anyone refer me how i can use it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This site is not for others to create your code but for you to get help with problems in your code. So please give it a try by yourself and if you have any problems you can come back with a concrete problem in your code.

Comment: First of all, do **not** use lowercase first letter when defining a type `seatcap`, use rather *CamelCase*, as suggested by the Java Naming Conventions. After that: this does not compile. E.g. `seatsize` is not defined. Edit your question and provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please.

Comment: You should do it yourself and ask if you having programming problems instead of asking how to do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to ignore the question headline because it doesn't make sense and only look at the question presented at the end of the OP.

> I have created a hashmap and mapped keys 1 to 100 to true. Now when
> user enters an integer number i should check whether the map contains
> the value true => user given integer number. Please anyone refer me
> how i can use it?

Use the `get(K)` method to find the value that a given key maps to.  The following is a simple approach.  If we assume that the key not being present or mapping to null is to be treated as false, then we can do the following.

```
int key = someUserInputs();
boolean isTrue = Boolean.TRUE.equals(map.get(key));
```